# Notebook does not always start up

Tags: boot, laptop

I have an ASUS notebook. Sometimes it doesn't start:

- Power LED is ON
- HDD is starting
- CPU is hot
- VGA is hot
- FAN didn't start
- No sound
- No image on external and internal display

This problem does not always happen, it just occurs sometimes.

Comment: Have you tried to reset your BIOS? What model is your Laptop?